# Помогите пожалуйста написать функцию

Tags: c

Нужно написать функцию для определения длины строки, полностью аналогичную библиотечной strlen.

Comment: Проходите посимвольно пока не встретите нулевой символ. Уж такой-то код вы написать сумеете?

Comment: К сожалению, в вузе не научили.

Comment: В большинстве вузов и не научат ничему полезному, только самому учиться и познавать, а не на кого-то надеяться

Comment: Поэтому, и задал вопрос, чтобы помогли разобраться

Comment: @ВадимВозвышаев, задавая вот такие вопросы, ты ничему и не научишься. Ну вот получил ты ответ, и что дальше? Нужно самому пробовать что-то делать, писать, приходить сюда с набросками и говорить что именно не работает. Иначе проще документы забрать с ВУЗа, если конечно ты туда не просто за корочкой, без обид :)

Comment: А книги на что? Или интернет? Когда делают за вас - это медвежья услуга...

Answer (score 1):

Каждая строка в Си заканчивается детерминирующим нулем (`\0`) и чтобы узнать длину строки достаточно пройти от начала и до этого нуля.

```
int strlen(char* str) {
    char* s = str;
    int size = 0;
    while (*s != '\0') {
        ++size;
        ++s;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Вот реализация покомпактнее:

```
int strlen1(char* str) {
    int size = 0;
    for (char* s = str; *s; ++s, ++size);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Ничего себе, даже на удаление ответ. Хмм

Comment: Откровенно говоря, делать за халявщиков ДЗ - это не помощь. Даже если ответ хороший :)

Comment: @Harry вряд ли написать простую функцию в 1 цикл это ДЗ. Скорей всего это какая-то часть домашней работы, но в любом случае, я думаю если привести теорию и пример реализации, то человек если хочет, то все поймет и ... В общем я думаю ответ подкрепленный теорией в любом случае поможет :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int strlen_custom(const char* str)
{
    int length = 0;
    while (str[length] != '\0')
        length++;
    return length;
}
```

Вариант через указатели

```
size_t strlen_custom(const char* str)
{
    const char* end = str;
    while (*end++);
    return end - str - 1;
}
```